# mysql insert/update non-breaking space

Tags: mysql

how to insert/update table by value with nonbreaking space.
the table charset is set to utf8, engine InnoDB
Mysql.

```
INSERT INTO table(field) VALUES REPLACE('some text',' ', CONVERT(C2A0 USING utf8))
```

something like that? not working

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO t1(field) VALUES (REPLACE('some text',' ', CONVERT(X'C2A0' USING utf8)));
```

Comment: I think that will be the solution, but got something like:
14:25:14 Kernel error: Error( 1270 ) HY000: "Illegal mix of collations (utf8_polish_ci,IMPLICIT), (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE), (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'replace'"